# problemas al ejecutar manage.py makemigrations en un projecto Django REST

Tags: djangorestframework

Estoy empezando a usar `django rest` siguiendo un tutorial en el cual la app es una catalogo de series.

Primeramente confirmo el modelo en el fichero models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Serie(models.Model):

    HORROR = 'horror'
    COMEDY = 'comedy'
    ACTION = 'action'
    DRAMA = 'drama'

    CATEGORIES_CHOICES = (
        (HORROR, 'Horror'),
        (COMEDY, 'Comedy'),
        (ACTION, 'Action'),
        (DRAMA, 'Drama'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES)
```

Siguiendo los pasos del tutorial... procedo a hacer la migracion del modelo:

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

y al ejecutarlo por consola... me lanza este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\WORK\Angular Proyecto\tutorial\webflix\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\P3DRUK0\Envs\evpy3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'series'
```

He indagado y no he dado con la solucion del problema... alguna ayuda me vendria bien...

gracias de antemano..

Comment: tienes instalada la app en los settings?

Comment: tengo incluido el app en el settings
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'series',
]

Comment: la estructura del proyecto es
carpeta general 'tutorial' con dos carpetas dentro: series(contiene los ficheros models, views, test serializers, apps, admin, la carpeta migrations); webflix(contiene el fichero manage.py y la carpeta webflix que a su ves contiene setting, urls, wsgi)

Answer (score 0):

en busca de solucion..y para salir de dudas...volvi a ejecutar el tutorial paso por paso y esta ves si se ejecuto correctamente el comando:

manage.py makemigrations

trate de ser lo mas minucioso posible...parece que fue algun problema de copilacion
gracias